# Lost network & video drivers after last reboot

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers

Yesterday morning I had a perfectly working Ubuntu 16.04 installation, rebooted for the first time in a while, so there had been a few updates installed since the last reboot.

When it came back up video resolution was poor and there was no network. I can't set a higher video resolution, attempts to fix the network problem seem to show there's no driver for the network card.

Also it seems to have only about a 50/50 chance of a reboot actually working, when it doesn't work there appears to be no video output at all.

To try and fix it I've used Rufus to create a boot USB with 16.04 (also later tried 17.04, but hit same problem) in the hope I could reinstall and fix the issues. If I let this go into the Try Ubuntu mode it all works perfectly, network is working fine, good video resolution.

If I try and install it it gets as far booting into Ubuntu with the wallpaper background, working toolbar showing a good network connection. But that's it, it doesn't do anything else, doesn't show any more activity, doesn't proceed with the install. I'm just left there with a minimal working Ubuntu that lets me play with the toolbar and that's about it.

I'm getting stuck for ideas here. Is there any possible quickfix where I can rollback the damage done by presumably one of the updates, one config file somewhere I can just patch up? Is there a way I can get the re-install to work? Last option would be to work out how to manually get the drivers back one by one, I get the feeling it may well be more than just the video and network drivers that need fixing here.

I have grabbed a copy of the 'etc' folder from the try Ubuntu installation to compare against my currently broken version in the hope I can find something to copy over from there to fix the problem, but I haven't been able to spot any likely candidates for a fix yet, but I'm still looking.

Thanks.

Comment: I found a fix, I was missing one obvious trick. The Try Ubuntu mode has an icon to install it, and it worked when launched from there.The 16.04 Installation didn't offer an install on top of existing installation option as I'd expected, only the option to wipe the existing installation or install alongside it. So I tried 17.04 and that allowed me to upgrade which fixed the problems, a few apps seem to be missing, but sure can sort that out. Still non the wiser to what the original problem was.